# CFG to Regular expression

Tags: regex, context-free-grammar

I am confused with this CFG. I want to convert it into a regular expression:

```
A -> aA | B | epsilon
B -> bB | A
```

Please also mention the conversion rule from CFG to RE.

Comment: Which language? [Perl?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) [Ruby?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) [Python?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: I suppose one possibility would be `[ab]*`, but there's really not enough information here. What's the start symbol, for one thing? A? or B? Or is there more to the grammar that you didn't include? Also, it smells a bit homework-ey...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you're talking about formal regular expression here.

Short answer: this is simply: `(a | b)*`.

Why? Let's see:

```
A -> aA | B | epsilon
B -> bB | A
```

This is equivalent to this grammar:

```
A -> aA 
A -> B
A -> epsilon
B -> bB
B -> A
```

See something here?

```
A -> B
B -> A
```

These are equivalent. Let's just replace `B` with `A`:

```
A -> aA 
A -> epsilon
A -> bA
```

Reorder this:

```
A -> aA 
A -> bA
A -> epsilon
```

Rewrite it with ORs

```
A -> aA | bA
A -> epsilon
```

Factor it:

```
A -> (a | b) A
A -> epsilon
```

Simplify:

```
A -> (a | b) A | epsilon
```

Which is:

```
A -> (a | b)*
```

Or, in concrete PCRE notation: `[ab]*`.

Also, it's not clear from your question, but you should be aware that [only some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) CFGs can be translated to regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks Bro the way you explained this cfg is great :)